# Updating a database table

Tags: c#, .net, database

I'm wondering if anyone could explain this to me:

I create a datarow with data from one of my databases

```
DataRow table = sessions.Tables["Sessions"].Rows[position];
```

I then make some changes to it and use the update command like this:

```
da.Update(sessions, "Sessions");
```

My question is, why does the "Sessions" database get updated with the value from "DataRow table"? I just took the values out..

What if I would like to make DataRow table1 and DataRow table2, change them both and later decide which one to use?

The rest of the code is in this thread if needed.

[Inserting a row into a database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11773201/inserting-a-row-into-a-database)

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

table1 and table2 and etc are all referencing the same DataRow objects in the table.

When you make a variable equal to an object (DataRow), it's only holding a reference to that object.

If you want table1 or table2 to just have a *copy* of the DataRow, then you would have to create a *new* DataRow and copy the columns and data accordingly.

Comment: Ahh, I see. Thank's a bunch :)